# Thread inside thread for saving image with OpenCV

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, opencv, python-multithreading

My scenario:
When I run program in new thread video stream is open from webcam and every 10 seconds I need to save image to database. Saving image in database I work in new thread. But when I make saving image video strem from webcam is frozen for 2-3 seconds. After 2-3 second video stream is working normally. I need to remove frozen from video stream.

main.py

```
import sys
import os
from program import Program

def main():
    pro = Program()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

program.py

```
import threading
import datetime
from mydb import MyDB
import time
import cv2
import os
import sys

class Program():
    def __init__(self):
        self.threadVideo =  None
        self.webcam = None
        self.frame = None
        self.rval = None
        self.saveImageToDB = MyDB()
        self.video()

    def video(self):
        self.threadVideo = threading.Thread(target=self.playVideo, args=())
        self.threadVideo.start()

    def playVideo(self):
        timeout = time.time() + 10
        self.webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        while True: 
            (self.rval, self.frame) = self.webcam.read()
            if time.time() > timeout:
                timeout = time.time() + 10
                thredSaveImage = threading.Thread(target=self.take())
                thredSaveImage.start()
            cv2.imshow('OpenCV', self.frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(10)

    def take(self):
        ts = datetime.datetime.now()
        filename = "{}.jpg".format(ts.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"))
        p = os.path.sep.join(("out", filename))
        cv2.imwrite(p, self.frame.copy())
        print("Image save local")
        self.saveImageToDB(p)
```

Comment: Problem is solved. Db needs to be in new thread

Comment: The lack of [synchronization](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm) between those threads is disturbing.

Comment: Please post a thorough answer to your own question, so that others can refer from it, and accept your own answer. Thanks